# React - syntax for passing computed styles to a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm very new to the language of react. I seem to continuously get an unexpected token error on the ":". What exactly is the syntax for putting multiple styles inside the Box component shown below? Alongside that, how does one go about putting multiple of these Box components, each one having its margin changed and put inside of an array, displayed on a website.

```js
ncaught SyntaxError: /Inline Babel script: Unexpected token, expected "}" (51:73)

const Box = (props) => <div style={"margin-left" : props.spacing, "width" : props.width, "height" : props.height, "background-color" : props.color}></div>
     |                                                                          
                                                 ^
```

The box component takes multiple sub-components such as margin-left (I'm not even sure if I can use this within React) and so on. I then have a for loop that continuously adds box components to an array each with a different margin so that it ends up really displaying a row of different elements inside the div.

```js
class StoryPage extends React.Component {
      render(){
         const Box = (props) => <div style={"margin-left" : props.spacing; "width" : props.width; "height" : props.height; "background-color" : props.color;}></div>
         const val = 0
         const boxArray = []
         for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
             val += 100
             boxArray.push(<Box spacing = {val} width = "100px" height = "100px" color = "black" />)
         }
         return(
              <div>
                {boxArray}
              </div>
         )
     }
 }
```

What I essentially expect to happen is have the array of box elements be displayed. However, I'm not really sure how I'm supposed to go about doing this.

Comment: Hi @Mahbod, check my answer and let me know if that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your “passing an object literal as a prop”-syntax is wrong** — explanation below.

---

React props are passed as follows:

- string literal

  ```
  <Component strProp='hello' />
  // or
  <Component strProp={'hello'} />
  ```
- variable

  ```
  <Component strProp={this.props.foo} />
  ```
- array literal

  ```
  <Component arrProp={[1, 2, 3]} />
  ```
- object literal

  ```
  <Component objProp={{foo: 'bar'}} />
  ```

See the double curly-brackets? One pair is needed to enclose *any* non-string-literal expression passed as prop, and the other is simply part of the object literal notation.

---

In contrast, this:

```
<Component objProp={foo: 'bar'} /> // <- WRONG
```

would **not** work because `foo: 'bar'` is not an expression.

Comment: Strings can be passed directly `propName="just a literal string"`.

Comment: True! Hmm should I include this or switch to an example with a Number to avoid distracting from the point? — edit: added to answer for completeness. Thank you!

Comment: @hugo Can you tell me what's wrong with my answer? Why the down vote?

Comment: Oh my lord, this is very interesting, kinda new to this but very handy of you to show it like this! I cant upvote because of my lack of reputation but definitely fixed my work!! @ravibagul91 your answer also helped out!! Thanks a bunch you guys

Answer (score 1):

Hugo is right. Also you don't want to add larger margin lefts to each element, margin-left specifies distance from border to element on the left. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model

You can set the property display to "inline" on all your divs to change the layout of divs from block to inline. Or just not do anything and they'll still all display.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
const Box = (props) => <div style={"margin-left" : props.spacing; "width" : props.width; "height" : props.height; "background-color" : props.color;}></div>
```

You have provide wrong `style` attribute, you need to provide like this:

```
const Box = (props) => (
  <div 
    style={{
      marginLeft: props.spacing, 
      width: props.width, 
      height: props.height, 
      backgroundColor: props.color
    }}
  />
);
```

Notice that `style` attribute should contain **double curly braces** and should separate properties with a **comma** `,`

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zauhp3)

**Note:** In React, inline style name should be in `camelCase`.

For Example,

- `margin-left` should be `marginLeft`.
- `background-color` should be `backgroundColor`.

Comment: I voted down because initially your answer was merely repeating a point that was already addressed hours before, in addition to providing no explanation regarding the actual *why* double brackets are needed (btw it’s not because the style attribute is special or magic, it’s because you’re passing an object literal). But I see you edited your answer to address the camel-case issue, which makes your answer more valuable imo. Let me remove the downvote :)

Comment: My vote is locked, I guess you had already edited when I voted. But if you edit a second time, I can fix it.

Comment: *(btw it’s not because the style attribute is special or magic, it’s because you’re passing an object literal)* Can you tell me where OP has passed object literal? I can see OP is just passing string, correct?

Comment: You just exaplain me where OP is `“passing an object literal as a prop”` which you have marked bold in your answer.

Comment: “it’s a syntax for inline style” no, that’s what I'm trying to explain: it’s a general syntax for passing anything other than a string literal. Read my answer, you will understand. **The inline styles are simply an object**, so yes, OP is trying to do that, but incorrectly so. That’s why I explain the correct way to pass an object literal. Does that make sense?